# Pthread Wrapper for Fortran

Tags: c++, fortran, pthreads, mixed-programming

I am newbie to both Fortran and C++, working on a task to couple two programs written in Fortran and C++.

I am trying to create a pthread(detached) wrapper and call it from my Fortran subroutine and pass a cpp function to it. I wrote some code  by following this link [Calling a subroutine in FORTRAN without blocking the main program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26791589/calling-a-subroutine-in-fortran-without-blocking-the-main-program).

I get run time error like below, when i execute it.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
```

I compiled using the following commands

```
gfortran-mp-4.7 -c pthread_mod.f90 
g++-mp-4.7 -c -std=c++11 pcmodel.cpp 
gfortran-mp-4.7 -c  mainFort.F
gfortran-mp-4.7 pthreads_module.o pcmodel.o mainFort.o -o test -lstdc++
```

Here is the minimal code where i can reproduce the error.

Pthreads_interface.h

```
extern "C" void pthread_create_opaque(pthread_t *threadptr, void *(**procptr)(void *), int *comerr){
  //   creates a new thread using an opaque pointer to the pthread_t structure
   pthread_attr_t  attr;
   pthread_attr_init(&attr);
   pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
   *comerr = pthread_create(threadptr, &attr, (*procptr), NULL);
}
```

pthreads_module.f90

```
module pthreads_module
implicit none
 interface

   subroutine pthread_create_opaque (threadptr, procptr, comerr) bind(C,name="pthread_create_opaque")
        USE ISO_C_BINDING
        type(c_ptr) :: threadptr
        type(c_funptr),value :: procptr
        integer(c_int),intent(out) :: comerr
   end subroutine

   subroutine PCModel () bind (c,name="PCModel_")
         USE ISO_C_BINDING
   end subroutine PCModel

  end interface
 end module pthreads_module
```

mainFort.F

```
program test
 call BCL00
end program test

  SUBROUTINE BCL00
  use pthreads_module
  USE ISO_C_BINDING
  implicit none
  type(c_ptr) :: threadptr
  integer :: comerr
  call pthread_create_opaque(threadptr,
 &          c_funloc(PCModel),comerr)

  END
```

where `PCModel`is the C++ function to be executed by pthread.

pcmodel.cpp

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include "pthreads_interface.h"
 using namespace std;

 void PCModel(){
      cout<<"PCModel is called"<<endl;
 }

 extern "C" void PCModel_(){
  PCModel();
 }
```

Ideally both my Fortran and C++ code should run in  parallel, once the fortran code triggers the thread to start the C++ function(`PCModel`)

It would be great, if some one could check the code and help me out.

Comment: yeah it is not declared, but i did it in mine.

Comment: Sounds good, will do it.

Comment: @Vladimir F tried it. it says `call pthread_create_opaque(c_loc(threadptr),                      
                                 1
Error: Type mismatch in argument 'threadptr' at (1); passed REAL(4) to TYPE(c_ptr)`

Comment: @Vladimir F  when i try declare `threadptr` as `type(c_ptr) :: threadptr` in `subroutine bcl00` it says `Error: Derived type 'c_ptr' at (1) is being used before it is defined`.

Comment: @Vladimir F added the code where is the error is reproduced.

Comment: After implementing them now i get 
`mainFort.F:18.32:


     &          c_funloc(PCModel),comerr)                               
                                1

Error: Symbol 'pcmodel' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type`

Comment: So I tried to add `type(c_funptr) :: PCModel`, the it compiled but throws a runtime error saying `Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference`

Comment: The problem with `pcmodel` is an important one.  If you can rephrase the question to focus on that then we can certainly answer.

Comment: Now I updated the current code.
@francescalus Yes you are right, there seems a problem with pcmodel, where my fortran program is unable to  pass it on to the thread properly.

Comment: You have to different PCmodels there, one in Fortran and one in C++. I am not sure what exactly `extern "C" void PCModel_(){
  PCModel();
 }` does in C++, but I am worried something fishy happens there.

Comment: Its working now, I am passing the `procptr` wrongly.

Comment: Can you post the solution as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

In Pthreads_interface.h I changed the way `procptr` is passed from `(*procptr)` to `procptr`

```
extern "C" void pthread_create_opaque(pthread_t *threadptr, void *(*procptr)(void *), int *comerr){
 //   creates a new thread using an opaque pointer to the pthread_t structure
 pthread_attr_t  attr;
 pthread_attr_init(&attr);
 pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
 *comerr = pthread_create(threadptr, &attr, procptr, NULL);
}
```

Now it runs without `Segmentation fault` and main program continues without waiting for the thread.